# Most efficient way to concatenate thousands of files in Perl

Tags: linux, perl

I'm looking for the most efficient way to concatenate thousands of files. The way I did it (Using Perl) until now is: I will open the source and the destination path and insert each line to the destination file.
Of course, it will take a lot of time. I thought of using the Linux command `cat` in order to solve this issue. But from past threads, I understood that cat has `MAX_ARG` that sets the limit to the command-line.
Consider you have an array `@paths` which contains all the paths to concatenate. What is the most efficient way possible, to concatenate thousands of files into one main file (order does not matter), using Perl?

**EDIT**: If that matters, the concatenate file could get up to `3GB`.

Comment: Read and write content in fixed sized chunks instead of line by line. $/ = \1024*1024*8;

Comment: Have a look at shelll command `xargs`. Maybe this can solve your issue of having too many files for the `cat` command.

Comment: Please show us the code you already have. Most likely it should be something like `use Path::Tiny; open my $out, '>', $outfilename or die "Couldn't write to '$outfilename': $!"; for my $in (@inputfiles) { print $out path($in)->slurp }`

Comment: Blocks of data instead of lines, using `sysread` and `syswrite`. Or possibly using `File::Map` instead to read the files.

Comment: Please allow us Google that for you: [concatenate files using perl](https://www.google.com/search?q=concatenate+files+using+perl)

Answer (score 0):

```
use IPC::Run qw( run );

run [ "xargs", "-0", "cat", "--" ],
   '<', \join("\0", @paths),
   '>', $output_qfn;
```

You could maybe use `find` to generate the list of files to concatenate.

```
use IPC::Run qw( run );

run [ "find", ..., "-print0" ],
   '|' [ "xargs", "-0", "cat", "--" ],
      '>', $output_qfn;
```

On a GNU system (e.g. Linux), you can avoid `xargs` when using `find`.

```
use IPC::Run qw( run );

run [ "find", ..., "-exec", "cat", "--", "{}", "+" ],
   '>', $output_qfn;
```

Comment: @KjetilS., That's not true. `-exec ... +` (as opposed to `-exec ... ;`) passes multiple paths per proces just like `xargs` does.

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice the `+` at the end of `-exec` and thought of the behaviour of `;` instead of `+`.